# How do I display HTML elements that span the width of the page inside width-restricted elements?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm working on a design that calls for the main body of the design to have a fixed pixel width of 940px, but for the top and bottom borders to extend past this boundary.

This is the simplest image that shows the desired effect:

[image: Example of desired effect]

Assuming some HTML like this:

```
<!-- This is the Big Black width restricted box -->
<div class="enclosingBox">
    <div class="topnav">
        Exclusives
        Shop
        The Brand
        Press
        Vault
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>This is some stuff in the middle</p>
        <p>Some Other Stuff in the middle</p>
    </div>

    <div class="bottomnav">
        SHOE PIC 1
        SHOE PIC 2
        SHOE PIC 3
        SHOE PIC 4
    </div>
</div>
```

The top navigation could be absolute positioned, but how would the markup for the bottomnav need to work?

Comment: Do you want the navigation elements to stay on page while scrolling ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking about it the wrong way. The best way to get the layout you're thinking of, if I understand you correctly, would be to create your page as horizontal 'segments' rather than trying to force an unnatural overlay.

```
<div style="width:800px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
 ... all the top stuff, 100% wide and smaller
</div>

<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="width:800px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
... your nav stuff
</div>
</div>

<div style="width:800px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
... you're body ...
</div>

<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="width:800px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
... bottom nav stuff
</div>
</div>

<div style="width:800px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
... all your feets are belong to div
</div>
```

Comment: I agree this is a potential solution, but it seems kind of odd semantically since the main "page" with the thick black borders does actually semantically contain the two navigation elements.

Comment: You could do the inverse of this, however, then you're messing with trying to keep the outer divs aligned with the main div when content is added. However, if you simply highlight the left and right borders in the inner divs, you will visually see a nice, continual border which appears to cross all of the elements. It will appear as quite a coherent singular rectangular box. I have used this very technique several times and it always comes out nicely. Plus, if you're going to use dynamic content, it gives you a nice natural break between elements. :)

Comment: Ok, looks like this is the best there is.  I guess this is probably better than absolutely positioned solutions.  I thought there might be some kind of margin trick, or relative positioning trick that could do the job but it seems clear there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this seems pretty close.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fq32a/2/

```
html, body { width: 100%; position: relative; }

.topnav {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100px; 
    height: 75px;
    left: 0px; 
    right: 0px;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    text-align: center;
}

.bottomnav {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 20px; 
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px; 
    right: 0px;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @danieltalsky - just read your comment to other answer, maybe this fiddle will at least get some one started. Will think on it some more myself.

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't consider the possibility of absolutely positioning the element from the bottom.  It's possible that could work but I'm still holding out for a solution that's a little less brittle than absolute positioning.

Comment: @danieltalsky - k, just updated my answer. Trick was `position: relative` on body. I thought that allowing absolute to bubble up to top would hit on body or html, but I guess it goes to document which isn't the true height of the page.

Comment: @danieltalsky - fair enough on holding out. I am also curious to see what other answers appear.

Comment: I personally think @mrtsherman solution would be better for the problem as it is easy enough to work with. Or you can try Thomas Wright's method as you can see that it is pretty straight-forward, **IF** the navigation doesn't have translucent backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
<div id="navigation">
   this is the navigation with 100% width.
</div>
<div id="width940">
  this is the container with 940px width
</div>

<!-- the css -->
#navigation {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  height:32px;
}
#width940 {
  width:940px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This works for the top navigation, where you know the height of the top navigation, but not for the bottom navigation.  If you read the question carefully, you'll see that's what I'm primarily asking about.

Comment: See, I say in the original question, at the end: "The top navigation could be absolute positioned, but how would the markup for the bottomnav need to work?"

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look into the over flow property. you can find the documentation on the w3. however, the answers posted using absolute positioning are good. it just gets quite quirky when dealing with older browsers so you will have to approach the problem from a trial and error basis. i am no css guru but i know a few things. the absolute positioning in theory should work, however, i have had problems with both the method i mentioned and the absolute positioning method, especially when its contained.